# Фильтрация внутреннего массива в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, filter, find

Имею коллекцию:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c7c804f14b4c026ba7fcaba"),

"values" : [ 
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 30,
    },

    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 33,
    },
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 34,
    },
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 35,
    },
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 36,
    }
]
```

}

Нужно получить результат:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c7c804f14b4c026ba7fcaba"),

"values" : [ 
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 30,
    },
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 34,
    },
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 35,
    },
    {
        "active" : true,
        "id" : 36,
    }
]
```

}

то есть не выводить value.id = 33 в результате.
Можно это сделать не через агрегацию ..aggregate(), а через find()? Может какой то javascript код с условием можно прикрутить, что не value.id = 33?

Comment: [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
db.test.find( { 'value.id': { $ne: 33 } } )
```

Comment: Хотя...наверное, такой запрос вернет документ,  где  `id != 33`

Comment: Да, такой вариант не подходит. Я нашел решение через .aggregate() и $filter
Пример:
db.getCollection("properties").aggregate(
    [
        {"$match":{"values.id":{"$in":[43]}}},
        {"$addFields":{"values":{"$filter":{"input":"$values","as":"value","cond":{"$setIsSubset":[["$$value.id"],[43]]}}}}}
    ]
)
Но проблема в том, что мне агрегация не подходит, я использую фреймворк Yii2, и такой запрос мне возвращает коллекцию обьектов, а мне нужен сам запрос для формирования активдатапровайдера.